# Mongo Db ESR rule for multiple index keys in a compound index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, compound-index

Collection: appointments

Schema:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId();
    userId: string;
    calType: string;
    status: string;
    appointment_start_date_time: string; //UTC ISO string
    appointment_end_date_time: string; //UTC ISO string
}
```

Example:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('6332b21960f8083d24f3140b')
    userId: "6272ccb3-4050-429c-b427-eb104f340962"
    calType: "MY Personal Cal"
    status: "CONFIRMED"
    appointment_start_date_time: "2022-07-08T03:30:00.000Z"
    appointment_end_date_time: "2022-07-08T04:00:00.000Z"
}
```

I want to create a compound index on `userId`, `calType`, `status`, `appointment_start_date_time`

Based on [Mongo Db's ESR rule](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/equality-sort-range-rule/#the-esr--equality--sort--range--rule) I would like to determine the arrangement of my keys.

The documentation conveniently gives an example of 3 keys in compound index where the first key is for equality, second for sort and third for range. But in my case I have more than 3 keys.

I would like to know how would the index keys be arranged for a more efficient compound index. In my case `userId`, `calType`, `status` will be used for equality based match whereas  `appointment_start_date_time` will be used for sorting.

Potential queries which I will be making on this collection will be:

1. All appointments where userId = x, calType = y, status = z sort by appointment_start_date_time ASC
2. All appointments where userId = x, status = z
3. All appointments where calType = y, status = z
4. All appointments where userId = x sort by appointment_start_date_time ASC or DSC

What is the standard when we have multiple keys for equality and one for sorting/range?

Comment: ESR refers arranging the order of keys in the index spec according to how you will query the collection.  What kind of queries do you expect your application to execute?

Comment: Let me add the potential queries which I will be making on the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your sample queries use a ranged filter.  Assuming none of these fields contain arrays, applying the ESR rule:

Queries 1 and 2 could be optimally served by an index on

```
{userId:1, status:1, calType:1, appointment_start_date_time:1}
```

Query 3 would be best server by this index:

```
{calType:1, status:1}
```

Query 4 would be best served by:

```
{userId:1, appointment_start_date_time:1}
```

In these optimal cases, the MongoDB server could seek to the first matching index key, scan to the last key in a single pass, and encounter the documents in already sorted order.

It may also be possible to get acceptable performance for queries 1,2, and 4 using the index:

```
{userId:1, appointment_start_date_time:1, status:1, calType:1}
```

Using this index, query 4 would still be optimal, but query 1 and 2 would require and additional index seek for each status/calType pair.  This would be somewhat less performant than the optimal case, but would still be better than an in-memory sort.

Comment: So when we have multiple keys in an index where does mongo apply the equality rule on? The first key, first two keys etc. I am confused about how mongo decides to apply equality on which keys, sorting on which and range on which when there are say more than 3 keys in a compound index

Comment: The server doesn't decide to apply equality.  `userId = x` is an equality test.

Comment: The ESR rule is a guideline for how to design an index.  It is not explicitly encoded in the server's source code

Comment: Ok, I thought it was encoded in Mongo on which key to match for equality , which for sorting etc. Thanks for clearing it out